# Active record organisation for maintainability and testability

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some of my AR classes are starting to... bulge around the waist.  I'm starting to think it might be time to put them on a diet.  Probably the biggest concern I have is that there's just so much code in one file, I'm considering breaking out validations, associations and groups of related methods into modules.  Are there any other alternatives I haven't considered?

I'd also like to do the same thing with my tests (I'm using shoulda with test/spec if that makes a different)...

Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404785/how-to-organize-rails-models-that-are-too-fat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm familiar with your problem. Some models in my projects were also getting too big to work pleasantly with them. I found a small piece of code (I think on [PaulBarry.com](http://paulbarry.com/articles/2008/08/30/concerned-with-skinny-controller-skinny-model)) which enables you to split your models into several files.

concerned_with makes it possible to place parts of your model in a subfolder. You put, for example, the following line in your original model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    concerned_with :validation
end
```

Then you create a file in 'models/user/validation.rb' which contains your validations:

```
class User
    validates_presence_of :username
end
```

Just put this code into an initializers file in your Rails project and you can use this nice feature!

```
class << ActiveRecord::Base
  def concerned_with(*concerns)
    concerns.each do |concern|
      require_dependency "#{name.underscore}/#{concern}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a good idea, however wouldn't the validation concern be: class Validation?

Comment: Ah, not it shouldn't be because you're reopening the user class.  Sorry, ignore that!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal to extract everything, or, most-common behaviour with associations into plugins with class methods like "acts_as_fat_model".

In general one of rails mvc idioms is "Fat models - skinny controllers". It's a good sign that your models (and not controllers) are fat.

Comment: I'm a preacher of the fat model/thin controller church.  The problem with fat models is that they're still fat =)